# Camel Blueprint Testing

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel, integration-testing, blueprint-osgi

I am fairly new to camel and blueprint test, I have a few routes enriching the request although while testing the same with Blueprint test, the endpoint is not being resolved.

I am using: 
Camel : 2.12.0.redhat-611412.
Fuse  : 6.1.1.
Blueprint test version: 2.12.0.redhat-611412.
Maven: 3.1.1.

Comment: 1. Be sure to have all the latest patches and update your dependencies to match latest camel-test-blueprint dependency.. i believe it is: 2.12.0.redhat-611454  2. blueprint-test can only run one CamelContext.. are all your routes in one context?   3. Any log messages?

Comment: I was giving the full path of my blueprint files from src/main/resources it turns out i had to only mention from the OSGI-INF path, which resolved the issue but gave me a new issue. Now my test just waits for 30 seconds and gives up waiting for the service, i tried to enable the full stack trace in maven and the error log is as: `MyTestClass->camelBlueprintTestSupport.setUp:183->CamelTestS‌​‌​upport.setUp():217‌​->‌​CamelTestSupport‌​.soS‌​etUp():247->Ca‌​melBlu‌​ePrintTestSu‌​pport.cr‌​eateCamelC‌​ontext:352 Runtime` I have no idea why the BlueprintTest is unable to create the camelContext

Answer (score 0):

> the endpoint is not being resolved.

It happens with Camel Blueprint tests mostly due to lack of necessary 'runtime' dependencies in `pom.xml`. Check the error log more closely and see if you can find any `ClassNotFoundException` errors.

Comment: I was giving the full path of my blueprint files from src/main/resources it turns out i had to only mention from the OSGI-INF path, which resolved the issue but gave me a new issue. Now my test just waits for 30 seconds and gives up waiting for the service, i tried to enable the full stack trace in maven and the error log is as: `MyTestClass->camelBlueprintTestSupport.setUp:183->CamelTestS‌​upport.setUp():217->‌​CamelTestSupport.soS‌​etUp():247->CamelBlu‌​ePrintTestSupport.cr‌​eateCamelContext:352 Runtime` I have no idea why the BlueprintTest is unable to create the camelContext.